# SQL cut results from table

Tags: sql

I have the following query:

```
    SELECT cust_id,cust_name,SUM(calls.duration) as duration
  FROM 
      calls, telephone

  WHERE calls.from_t_no = telephone.t_no
  AND
  calls.duration <=60

  group by telephone.cust_id, telephone.cust_name
```

Which give the following results;

```
cust_id cust_name duration
0123456789  Avi 18
1234567890  Benny   27
2345678901  Gadi    13
3456789012  Dalia   69
4567890123  Hilla   5
5678901234  Varda   14
7890123456  Haim    20
8901234567  Tali    20
9012345678  Yoram   46
```

I also have this query:

```
SELECT cust_id,cust_name,SUM(calls.duration) as duration 
      FROM calls ,telephone
      WHERE to_t_no = telephone.t_no
      AND
      calls.duration >=500
      group by telephone.cust_id, telephone.cust_name
```

Which provides the following results:

```
cust_id cust_name   duration
2345678901  Gadi    50022
4567890123  Hilla   50000
```

the second query is actually another filter or condition which the first query should match.
I cannot include the second query within the first query because it uses different columns.
I need to "subtract" the second query from the first query.

How do I do that?

Comment: you have `calls.duration <=60` in the first and `calls.duration >=500
` in the second query which makes the result sets IMHO mutually exclusive... so what exactly do you mean by `the second query is actually another filter or condition which the first query should match` ?

Comment: first query has: "WHERE calls.from_t_no = telephone.t_no" , second query has : "WHERE to_t_no = telephone.t_no"

Comment: ok - so what is the filter you want to apply ? only the same cust_id from both should appear ?

Comment: cust_id,cust_name,SUM(calls.duration) should appear in the result. it appears in both SELECT statement. the first query should not include customers which are not in the second query results (Gadi and Hilla in this case)

Comment: @Gil what do you mean *"the second query ... uses different columns"*. As far as I can see both queries select same columns from same tables and have same `GROUP BY`. Am I missing something obvious here ;) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you truly can't merge the queries, you can JOIN the results like this:

```
SELECT T0.cust_id, T0.cust_name, T0.duration FROM

(  SELECT cust_id,cust_name,SUM(calls.duration) as duration
FROM 
    calls, telephone

WHERE calls.from_t_no = telephone.t_no
AND
calls.duration <=60

group by telephone.cust_id, telephone.cust_name) T0

JOIN

(SELECT cust_id,cust_name,SUM(calls.duration) as duration 
  FROM calls ,telephone
  WHERE to_t_no = telephone.t_no
  AND
  calls.duration >=500
  group by telephone.cust_id, telephone.cust_name) T1

ON T0.cust_id = T1.cust_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to post the complete structure of your table and describe what you really need.

If i understand correctly the problem the conditions that you are exposing are mutually exclusive. I think that there is not possible that any record match both conditions because the final query will look like this:

```
SELECT cust_id,cust_name,SUM(calls.duration) as duration 
FROM calls ,telephone
WHERE 
    to_t_no = telephone.t_no
    AND calls.from_t_no = telephone.t_no
    AND calls.duration <=60
    AND calls.duration >=500
group by telephone.cust_id, telephone.cust_name;
```

If what you want is a general solution to make a *"query over a query"* you can use this kind of sentence:

```
SELECT field1, field2 FROM
    (SELECT field1, field2, ..., fieldn FROM table WHERE condition) AS filteredTable
WHERE anyCondition;
```